Incorrect Line Numbers in Call Stack from Azure Application Insights for .NET 6.0 Production Environment
I'm experiencing an issue with incorrect line numbers being reported in the call stack from Azure Application Insights in our .NET 6.0 production environment. The problem seems to be inconsistent and occurs in multiple places throughout our codebase.
Here's an example of the issue:
System.NullReferenceException:
   at LEA.Novo.Services.Packages.ProductSupply.ProductSupplyPackageFlowService.ApplyStepOrder (LEA.Novo, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: D:\a\1\s\source\backend\Customers\Novonordisk\LEA.Novo\Services\Package\ProductSupply\ProductSupplyPackageFlowService.cs:679)
   at LEA.Novo.Services.Packages.ProductSupply.ProductSupplyPackageFlowService+<RefreshPackageFlow>d__12.MoveNext (LEA.Novo, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: D:\a\1\s\source\backend\Customers\Novonordisk\LEA.Novo\Services\Package\ProductSupply\ProductSupplyPackageFlowService.cs:100)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at LEA.WebApi.Controllers.PackageControllers.PackageFlowController+<RefreshPackageFlow>d__4.MoveNext (LEA.WebApi, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: D:\a\1\s\source\backend\LEA\LEA.WebApi\Controllers\PackageControllers\PackageFlowController.cs:46)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at lambda_method24673 (Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor+AwaitableObjectResultExecutor+<Execute>d__0.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker+<<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Logged|12_1>d.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker+<<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0>d.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker+<<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0>d.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker+<<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0>d.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker+<<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0>d.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker+<<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1>d.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker+<<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1>d.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware+<<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0>d.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler+<HandleAsync>d__0.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware+<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at LEA.Middleware.MW00_ExceptionHandler+<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext (LEA.WebApi, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: D:\a\1\s\source\backend\LEA\LEA.WebApi\Middleware\MW00_ExceptionHandler.cs:32)


In this example, ProductSupplyPackageFlowService.cs:100 appears to be correct, but there's no logical reason for the exception to occur on ProductSupplyPackageFlowService.cs:679 (please refer to the two screenshots for more information. This discrepancy in line numbers is not isolated to this specific case and has been observed in other parts of the application as well.
Questions:

What could be causing these incorrect line numbers in the call stack?
Is this a known issue with Azure Application Insights or .NET 6.0?
Are there any configuration settings or best practices that could help resolve this problem?
How can I ensure accurate line number reporting in our production environment?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
enter image description here
enter image description here
Tried to check by disabling C# JIT optimization did not help.

var grouped = updated.GroupBy(u => u.PackageId);
foreach (var group in grouped)
{
    var package = packages
        .Where(p => p.Id == group.Key)
        .SingleOrThrowNotFound();

    var packageProperties = await _packageService.GetPackageProperties(package.PackagePropertyIds);

    var launchSpeedProperty = packageProperties.FirstOrDefault(prop => prop.PackagePropertyTypeId == launchSpeed?.Id);
    var launchTypeProperty = packageProperties.FirstOrDefault(prop => prop.PackagePropertyTypeId == launchType?.Id);
    var itemTypeProperty = packageProperties.FirstOrDefault(prop => prop.PackagePropertyTypeId == itemType?.Id);

    var inputNumber = new ProductSupplyRefreshInput(launchSpeedProperty?.Number,
        launchTypeProperty?.Number,
        itemTypeProperty?.Number);

    var allSteps = CreatePackageSteps();

    ////Set step order
    ApplyStepOrder(allSteps, launchTypeProperty);

    var packagePropertyIds = new ProductSupplyRefreshInput(packageProperties.FirstOrDefault(prop => prop.PackagePropertyTypeId == launchSpeed?.Id)?.Id,
            packageProperties.FirstOrDefault(prop => prop.PackagePropertyTypeId == launchType?.Id)?.Id,
            packageProperties.FirstOrDefault(prop => prop.PackagePropertyTypeId == itemType?.Id)?.Id);


    //Set lead time
    await ApplyLeadTime(allSteps, packageStepTypes, launchSpeed, launchType, itemType, packagePropertyIds);

    var _steps = group;
    ////Merge available steps into basic package flow
    MergePackageSteps(allSteps, _steps, packageStepTypes);

    //If 'Standard launch' then update action date based on launch date input 
    if (inputNumber.LaunchSpeed.HasValue && inputNumber.LaunchSpeed.Value == LaunchSpeed.StandardLaunch.PackageType)
    {
        await CalculationActionDate(allSteps, meta, inputNumber, launchTypeProperty);

        // For standard launch, calculation should start from Action Date
        var actionDateStep = allSteps.Single(a => a.PackageStepType == ProductSupplyPackageStepType.ActionDate);
        actionDateStep.ClearPreSteps(); 
    }

    // Refresh package flow by starting from HA approval date
    var startStep = allSteps.Single(a => a.PackageStepType == ProductSupplyPackageStepType.HaApproval);

    //Apply Is Milestone
    foreach(var step in allSteps)
    {
        step.IsMilestone = packageStepTypes.Single(pst => pst.Number == (int)step.PackageStepType).IsMilestone;
        step.EndDateIsAuto = step.IsMilestone || step.EndDateIsAuto;
    }

    await CalculateDates(allSteps, startStep, ProductSupplyFlowCalculationDirection.Forward, meta, inputNumber);

    //Calculate fixed PA date
    var paDate = await CalculateStepsBackwardsDate(ProductSupplyPackageStepType.ProductAvailability, allSteps, meta, inputNumber, launchTypeProperty);
    var paStep = allSteps.Single(a => a.PackageStepType == ProductSupplyPackageStepType.ProductAvailability);
    if (paDate.HasValue && paStep.StartDateIsAuto)
    {
        paStep.StartDate = paDate;
    }

    // TODO: Need to fix Status and Step Type
    result.AddRange(allSteps.Select(s => new PackageStepDTO()
    {
        PackageId = group.Key,
        PackageStepStatusId = s.PackageStepStatusId,
        PackageStepTypeId = packageStepTypes.FirstOrDefault(pst => pst.Number == (int)s.PackageStepType)?.Id ?? 0,
        CompletionDate = s.CompletionDate,
        CompletionDateIsAuto = true, //Always true for NN
        EndDate = s.EndDate,
        EndDateIsAuto = s.EndDateIsAuto,
        StartDate = s.StartDate,
        StartDateIsAuto = s.StartDateIsAuto,
        IsActive = s.IsActive,
        ResponsibleUserId = s.ResponsibleUserId,
        Duration = IsStepWithManualDuration(s.PackageStepType) ? (int?)s.DurationWorkingDays : null
    }));

    await CalculatePackageWarning(package, allSteps, packageWarnings);
    CalculatePackageStepStatus(result, packageStepTypes, package);
    CalculatePackageStatus(package, packageStepTypes, result);
}

private void ApplyStepOrder(IEnumerable<TemporaryPackageStep> steps, PackagePropertyDTO launchType)
{
    if (launchType.Code == "LM") // Local manufacturing
    {
        AddStepNavigation(steps, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.HaApproval, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.ActionDate);
        AddStepNavigation(steps, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.ActionDate, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.RIMS);
        AddStepNavigation(steps, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.ActionDate, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.RALabel);
        AddStepNavigation(steps, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.RALabel, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.SoOp);
        AddStepNavigation(steps, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.RIMS, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.RABom);
        AddStepNavigation(steps, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.SoOp, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.ReadyToShip);
        AddStepNavigation(steps, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.RABom, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.ReadyToShip);
        AddStepNavigation(steps, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.ReadyToShip, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.LD);
        AddStepNavigation(steps, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.LD, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.ProductAvailability);
        AddStepNavigation(steps, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.ProductAvailability, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.PackQA);
        AddStepNavigation(steps, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.PackQA, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.LocalHandling);
        AddStepNavigation(steps, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.LocalHandling, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.Launch);
    }
    else if (launchType.Code == "Dialoq") // Dialoq flow
    {
        AddStepNavigation(steps, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.HaApproval, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.ActionDate);
        AddStepNavigation(steps, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.ActionDate, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.RIMS);
        AddStepNavigation(steps, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.ActionDate, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.RALabel);
        AddStepNavigation(steps, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.RIMS, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.PackQA);
        AddStepNavigation(steps, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.RALabel, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.RABom);
        AddStepNavigation(steps, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.RABom, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.SoOp);
        AddStepNavigation(steps, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.SoOp, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.PackQA);
        AddStepNavigation(steps, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.PackQA, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.ReadyToShip);
        AddStepNavigation(steps, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.ReadyToShip, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.LD);
        AddStepNavigation(steps, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.LD, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.ProductAvailability);
        AddStepNavigation(steps, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.ProductAvailability, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.LocalHandling);
        AddStepNavigation(steps, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.LocalHandling, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.Launch);
    }
    else
    {
        //Standard flow
        AddStepNavigation(steps, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.HaApproval, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.ActionDate);
        AddStepNavigation(steps, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.ActionDate, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.RIMS);
        AddStepNavigation(steps, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.ActionDate, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.RALabel);
        AddStepNavigation(steps, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.RALabel, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.SoOp);
        AddStepNavigation(steps, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.RIMS, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.RABom);
        AddStepNavigation(steps, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.SoOp, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.PackQA);
        AddStepNavigation(steps, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.RABom, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.PackQA);
        AddStepNavigation(steps, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.PackQA, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.ReadyToShip);
        AddStepNavigation(steps, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.ReadyToShip, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.LD);
        AddStepNavigation(steps, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.LD, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.ProductAvailability);
        AddStepNavigation(steps, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.ProductAvailability, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.LocalHandling);
        AddStepNavigation(steps, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.LocalHandling, ProductSupplyPackageStepType.Launch); /// Failing line
    }
}

private void AddStepNavigation(IEnumerable<TemporaryPackageStep> steps, ProductSupplyPackageStepType from, ProductSupplyPackageStepType to)
{
    var _from = GetStepByPackageStepType(steps, from);
    var _to = GetStepByPackageStepType(steps, to);

    if (_from == null || _to == null)
    {
        _logger.LogDebug("Step type is not found: From = " + from.ToString() + ", To = " + to.ToString() );
        return;
    }

    _from.AddPost(_to);
}


Please provide code in text format

Thank you for the reply @Harshitha. I'm adding the code as well.

Are you building in "Debug" or "Release" configuration? Also, what is happening inside "AddStepNavigation()"?

This is a release build. However the other lines match fully. Just the last part of the Call Stack is incorrect.
I have added the code AddStepNavigation() for you.

The method might be encountering a null reference when trying to call _from.AddPost(_to) if _from or _to is null.

First of all, it should not as there is a condition before that line that is checking for null and returning of _from or _to is null.
Secondly, the call stack should log this method (AddStepNavigation) if the null pointer exception is happening from inside this method.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.


First of all, it should not as there is a condition before that line that is checking for null and returning of _from or _to is null.

Then it should prevent null pointer exceptions from occurring inside the method. However, if an exception does happen within the method, it should be logged accurately, including capturing the method name in the call stack.

The AddStepNavigation method checks for null references before proceeding. If a null reference is found, it logs the issue and returns without further processing.

Check that exceptions are logged correctly and that the method name and stack trace are included in the logs. This will help diagnose any issues accurately.


Revised Code:
private void AddStepNavigation(IEnumerable<TemporaryPackageStep> steps, ProductSupplyPackageStepType from, ProductSupplyPackageStepType to)
{
    try
    {
        var _from = GetStepByPackageStepType(steps, from);
        var _to = GetStepByPackageStepType(steps, to);

        if (_from == null || _to == null)
        {
            // Log a warning if the steps are not found
            _logger.LogWarning("Step type is not found: From = {From}, To = {To}", from, to);
            return;
        }

        _from.AddPost(_to);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Log the exception including the method name
        _logger.LogError(ex, "Exception occurred in {MethodName} with From = {From} and To = {To}", nameof(AddStepNavigation), from, to);
        // Send the exception details to Application Insights
        _telemetryClient.TrackException(ex);
        _telemetryClient.Flush();
    }
}


try-catch block is added to handle any unexpected exceptions within the AddStepNavigation method and the LogError method logs the exception, including the method name and parameters, ensuring the stack trace includes AddStepNavigation.

.csproj configuration generates portable PDB files and includes them in the release builds.
By this we can be able to capture and diagnose issues in the AddStepNavigation method and other parts of your application.


Thanks a lot. Looks like it worked. But I will update if I run into same issue.
